# Backbone view click checkbox listener

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML > 
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

        <script src="jquery.js">
    </script> 

    <script src="underscore.js">

    </script> 
    <script src="backbone.js">
    </script> 
    <script>
        var View = Backbone.View.extend({

            el: '#listen_to_box',

            events: { 
                'click [type="checkbox"]':'clicked',
            },
        clicked : function(event ) { 
            console.log("events handler for "+  this.el.outerHTML);
        }
    });

    </script>

    <div id="listen_to_box">
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The clicked function is not getting called when i click the checkbox , please help me out with associating a listener function for the click event on the checkbox . Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You code looks perfect. You have defined the `Backbone View` called `View` and the events are attached when try to create a new instance on the View.. So the event is never attached..

Just create a new instance and your code should work.

`var view = new View();`   **or**   `new View()`   should do

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vMYKY/)**

You code runs before the element is encountered on the page. To make it work you either need to move the code just before the closing tag or encase your code inside `Document Ready handler`

```
$(function() {
     // Your code here
});
```

Comment: I tried it , still not working :( nothing is getting printed on the console on click of the checkbox :( please help me out with this .

Comment: Looks like your script runs before the element is present on the screen.. Encase your code inside `document.ready` event

Comment: @KarthicRao.. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Here is my blog on the above topic [link](http://hackintoshrao.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/backbone-js-listening-to-dom-events-using-backbone-views/)

Comment: Can you please answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725140/how-to-do-backbone-image-slider

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are passing in `el` when you are defining your `View` class, instead of passing it in when you instantiate the `View` class. Try this instead:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click [type="checkbox"]': 'clicked',
    },
    clicked: function (event) {
        console.log("events handler for " + this.el.outerHTML);
    }
});

// Pass in el when instantiating the view
new View({
    el: $("#listen_to_box")
});
```

See a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/lolson/PxFQ8/).

Answer (score 0):

```
change to  
clicked: function (event) {
    console.log("events handler for " + this.$el.outerHTML);
}
```

see if it helps