# How to do backbone image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I am learning backbone and am not aware much in backbone.I need to do image slider using backbone.Though I can do using jquery like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HLHrG/)

The link is the demo as per my requirement.There are in total 3 images.When you click on the last image then 1st two images disappears and new 2 images appear.

Can anybody please guide me how to do similarly using backbone.

This is my code using jquery

```
<img id="image-1" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/abstract">
<img id="image-2" src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/food">
<img id="arrow" src="http://placehold.it/50x100">
$('#arrow').click(function() {
    $('#image-1').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/150/100/city');
    $('#image-2').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/150/100/sports');
});
```

Any help will be upvoted

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are Backbone Views.

I personally really like the [TodoMVC example](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/), which is complete introduction to Backbone and its different components.

What you will need to do is to first wrap your content into a identifiable div, something like:

```
<div id="slideshow">
  <ul class="images">
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/abstract" /><li>
    <li><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/100/food" /><li>
  </ul>

  <a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
</div>
```

Note that:

1. I only use an ID for the wrapper, *not* inside of it. It's preferable since backbone views have nice mechanism to work only with its own content (look at [events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) and [selector](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar)).
2. I wrap images inside a `<ul>`. Again, only in the purpose of making the structure more meaningful and querying easier.

Then, your view code should look like:

```
var MySuperView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    "click .next": "next"
  },
  interval: 1000,

  initialize: function() {
    // this is like a constructor
    var _this = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.next(); // calling next() every `interval` ms
    }, _this.interval);
  },

  next: function() {
    // here goes your logic
    return false;
  }
});
```

And finally, to bind the view to the matching element:

```
var view = new MySuperView();
view.setElement(document.getElementById("slideshow"));
```

And voilà :)

Comment: Can you provide me an jsfiddle?

Comment: This would not work out of the box, you need to fit in your logic into it :)

Comment: I have done this as per your answer http://jsfiddle.net/vMYKY/19/ its printing `hi` in the console when I click `next`.Can you please tell me how to load images when `next` is pressed